# access denied while deleting file

Tags: c#, file

while deleting its throwing error Access Denied ...

```
sSystemFolder = "c:\\";


 if (File.Exists(sSystemFolder + "\\Registry.txt"))

                {

                    File.Delete(sSystemFolder + "\\Registry.txt");
                    StreamWriter SW;
                    sSystemFolder = sSystemFolder + "\\Registry.txt"; ;
                    SW = File.CreateText(sSystemFolder);
                    SW.WriteLine(Rkey + ";" + Nofu + ";" + Date + ";" + Status);
                    SW.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    StreamWriter SW;
                    sSystemFolder = sSystemFolder + "\\Registry.txt"; ;
                    SW = File.CreateText(sSystemFolder);
                    SW.WriteLine(Rkey + ";" + Nofu + ";" + Date + ";" + Status);
                    SW.Close();
                }
```

could anyone point me where is the error?

Comment: The user account running ASP.NET should have write access to that file and parent folder. This is most probably not the case, or this file is write-protected, or even still open, explaining the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No error. Access is denied. Check file access.

And realize that C: - system root - requires elevation to make anything. Not a good idea to store anything in that place. It is against best practices. The file should not be there.

Comment: Depends what the file is for. User specific? Profile. Machine specific - There is a special folder in which you are supposed to make a subfolder. Check the special folder collection for locations with a meaning. Puttingnoise into the system root drive is as bad as it get and screams "ignorant, never learned windows system rules for well behaving programs".